# AccessKey Highlighter angular library

Tags: html, angular

I was wondering if there is a angular library to visually display what accesskeys are assigned to what html elements when ALT key is pressed.

I can use the below to capture the keyboard event and implement something but checking to see if there is a better way or an library that does what i am look for.

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
if (event.altKey) {
  // ...
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Angular provides a nice high level API for listening to keydown events. You do not need to access the `$event`. You can use `keydown.ACCESS_KEY.KEY` syntax in the `HostListener` definition. Like this:

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[altKey]',
})
export class AltKeyDirective  {
  @HostListener('keydown.p') onP() {
    console.log('p pressed');
  }

  @HostListener('keydown.alt') onAlt() {
    console.log('alt pressed');
  }

  @HostListener('keydown.alt.p') onAltP() {
    console.log('alt+p pressed');
  }
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/alt-key-listener)

There is also the `Renderer2` class with `listen` method with the following definition:

```
listen(target: 'window' | 'document' | 'body' | any, eventName: string, callback: (event: any) => boolean | void): () => void
```

[Renderer2  docs](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#listen)

Comment: nice to know Angular provides high level API. i think i should elaborate my question a bit more. after posting i searched and found a plugin [link](https://github.com/DamianEdwards/KeyTips-jQuery-Plugin) that does exactly what i am trying to achieve however its in jquery. i am not sure if i should install jquery in my angular app can you or some one suggest a best approach or any alternative similar to the link that can be implement in angular?

Comment: Do not use jQuery with Angular. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to highlight the input box after user presses the access key? Btw, please upvote my answer if you think it's helpful :)

Comment: yes, something similar. i have several controls(anchor/button) on my form(s) on holding the alt key i am trying to highlight the access key value on the form eg: **ALT+ S** only **S** , **ALT+ Q** only **Q** ...  will be highlighted on the form so user can see all the shortcuts while holding the ALT key and releasing it hides.

Comment: Do you want to highlight the entire input element or just the letters? For entire input check this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jqkwam

Comment: just the letter on many buttons on your demo the focus had to be on the input control.